# DateTime formatting to have trailing zeroes and snap to milli, micro or nano format

Tags: java, scala

I have some code like this

```
import java.time.Instant


val tstamp = 1546344620.1877
val nanoAdj = ((BigDecimal(tstamp) - tstamp.toLong) * 1000000000).toLong
Instant.ofEpochSecond(tstamp.toLong, nanoAdj).toString
// will print : 2019-01-01T12:10:20.187700Z
```

The `toString` from the Instant object created from `ofEpochSecond` is great with trailing zeroes to milli/micro/nano group, but I'm struggling to get the formatted to do the same. I need to change the format a little to something like `2019-01-01 12:10:20.187700 UTC`

Other examples:

```
2019-01-01 12:10:20 UTC // no fractions
2019-01-01 12:10:20.180 UTC // milliseconds
2019-01-01 12:10:20.187700 UTC // microseconds
2019-01-01 12:10:20.187738200 UTC // nanoseconds
```

I'm using DateTimeFormatter like below, but I'm open for other suggestions.

```
def formatter: DateTimeFormatter = {
      val tz_format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .optionalStart
        .parseCaseSensitive()
        .appendZoneRegionId()
        .toFormatter

      val datetime_format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
        .toFormatter

      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(datetime_format)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(tz_format)
        .toFormatter
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `DateTimeFormatter` doesn't support that, and because it is `final`, you cannot even extend it with such functionality.

Comment: @Andreas any other formatter that will do the job?

Comment: Only one you write yourself. I'd suggest writing a formatter that uses `DateTimeFormatter` with 9 fractional digits, then remove then in blocks of 3 when zero, e.g. using regex.

Comment: As far I see the double input can represent microseconds precisely, while nanos will be rounded in any case... Then why do you use `BigDecimal` instead of just `(tstamp - tstamp.toLong) * 1000000000` for calculation of nano adjustment?

Comment: BTW, I'm able to provide the most efficient solution for you, but just curios which system/library/framework provides doubles as timestamps for you?

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk, it came in as a String from BigQuery. And I use BigDecimal because calculation using Double gives weird inaccurate results.

Comment: This is much better! Am I right understand that you can skip using of `tstamp` which is defined as a `double` primitive and just use `BigDecimal` instead?

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas said in the comment, the class for formatting, `DateTimeFormatter`, does not support this nifty functionality. My best suggestion is to leverage `LocalTime.toString()`, which has it. In Java syntax (sorry, I haven’t got a Scala development environment):

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd ");

private static String formatEpochSeconds(String epochSeconds) {
    BigDecimal totalSeconds = new BigDecimal(epochSeconds);
    long seconds = totalSeconds.longValue();
    long nanos = totalSeconds.subtract(new BigDecimal(seconds))
            .multiply(new BigDecimal(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)))
            .longValue();
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanos)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    return dateTime.format(dateFormatter)
            + dateTime.toLocalTime()
            + " UTC";
}
```

Try it out:

```
    System.out.println(formatEpochSeconds("1546344600.0"));
    System.out.println(formatEpochSeconds("1546344620.0"));
    System.out.println(formatEpochSeconds("1546344620.18"));
    System.out.println(formatEpochSeconds("1546344620.1877"));
    System.out.println(formatEpochSeconds("1546344620.1877382"));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2019-01-01 12:10 UTC
> 2019-01-01 12:10:20 UTC
> 2019-01-01 12:10:20.180 UTC
> 2019-01-01 12:10:20.187700 UTC
> 2019-01-01 12:10:20.187738200 UTC
> ```

The seconds are omitted completely if they are 0.0. If you don’t want this, you will need to code a special case.